# Japanese Email Webfont

Tags: html, css, html-email, webfonts, cjk

I've been working on an email template with Japanese characters and annoyed for days about this issue.

The problem is, my desired output for font rendering on an email template is not achieved. I'm trying to use Noto Sans JP font as it is free on Google Font but the output in the email provider (tested on: Gmail and Yahoo) is different.

So, is there any workaround about this if I insist on using Noto Sans JP font or do I have to abandon the thought of using it and try another font? And is there any webfont for Japanese that is good for email?

I'm testing my html-email validity here: https://www.htmlemailcheck.com/check/.
Send email test here: https://putsmail.com/tests/new

Please check my code below also:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ジャパン</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+JP:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap&subset=japanese" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Roboto; font-weight: 400">
        <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 740px;max-width: 100%;margin: 0 auto;padding: 0 10px;font-weight: 400;line-height: 1.3em;position: relative;color: #646464;">
        <tr>
            <td class="section" style="padding: 50px;">
                <h1 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Roboto;font-size: 28px;color: #505050;margin:0 0 13px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-weight: 700;">お問い合わせを</h1>
                <h2 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Roboto;font-size: 28px;color: #505050;margin:0 0 35px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-weight: 400;">受け付けました。</h2>
                <p style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Roboto;font-size: 14px;color: #646464;font-weight: 400;margin:0;">こんにちは。
                    <b style="font-weight: 700;">マーク</b>様
                </p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Roboto;font-size: 14px;color: #646464;font-weight: 400;margin:0;">お問い合わせいただきありがとうございます。</p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Roboto;font-size: 14px;color: #646464;font-weight: 400;margin:0;">通常、翌営業日内までに担当スタッフより回答をご案内しております。</p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Roboto;font-size: 14px;color: #646464;font-weight: 400;margin:0;">今しばらくお待ちください。</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a read of **[Guide to Webfonts](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts)**. Custom fonts aren't yet universally supported inside of email providers.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that. And I even tried import and font-face but failed. Well, the samples are okay if it is English characters, but I'm struggling coz it's Japanese. Any suggestions can you give?

Comment: <html lang="ja-jp" /> Have you tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MattHamer5 mentioned this in a comment already but it seems to have been brushed passed.
The article he referenced also mentions this - https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Custom fonts won't work in some email clients. 
One big one they won't work in, Gmail. Seems odd since their parent company runs Google Fonts. 
Trust me, we've all gone round in circles asking why this feature isn't integrated into Gmail, but no word from Gmail on this.

No amount CSS font imports will fix this issue. It's a basic lack of integration in Gmail (unless you have the font installed on your machine/device).

Typically, we rely on fallback web safe fonts such as Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Georgia etc, to allow any email clients that do not support custom fonts, to gracefully fallback to a font that works best for our design/brand.
So your font declaration could read like this:

```
font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Or it'll be optimised to declare the web safe fonts that work best for Japanese characters.

Comment: Not an answer, but you have a point for a good explanation. I just gave up and ended on this line of code, I don't know if this is a good practice though: font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', 'Montserrat', 'Mplus 1p', 'Hiragino Sans', 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro', '游ゴシック' , '游ゴシック体' , YuGothic , 'Yu Gothic', 'ＭＳ ゴシック' , 'MS Gothic', sans-serif;

Comment: I got that from this article: https://medium.com/@PavelLaptev/japanese-typography-on-the-web-tips-and-tricks-981f120ad20e

Comment: Not an answer? I would say this definitively answers that there are no workarounds to fix the issue in every email clients and how to set fallbacks up. However, I'm not here for points or bragging rights, so no biggie :)  Honestly, as long as you test that declaration in as many email clients as possible and it works where you need it to, then I don't see any issue with that declaration.

Comment: Obviously I'll advise the use of Email on Acid or Litmus for thorough testing. But an alternative if you can't afford those services, could be setting up test accounts in each of the email providers and on as many different devices as you can.

Comment: Yeah right, I've taken a look about acid and litmus. Gonna try testing. Thank you :)